# Aggregating data from different Schemas, where one schema has array type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have 2 different Schemas (i.e Users, Posts), Users has one object i.e Followers which is of array data type, I am trying to aggregate all the posts from the users, which has req.user.id or logged in user's id inside the "Followers" array.

This is User Schema:

```
followers: [

{
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
},]
```

This is the get request I am using:

```
try {

 const posts = await Post.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: "users",
       localField: "user",
       foreignField: "followers.user",
       as: "followers",
     },
   },{$match: {'followers.user' : req.user.id }}
])
res.json(posts);
```

This returns: [ ] as output

Answer (score 0):

```
followers: [

  {
    user: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "user",
  },
},]
```

if field followers above is in Post schema,

```
 const posts = await Post.aggregate([
 {
   $lookup: {
     from: "users",
     localField: "followers.user",  <- field relation in Post
     foreignField: "_id", <- field objectId in users maybe "_id" 
     as: "followers",
   },
 },{$match: {'followers.user' : req.user.id }}
 ])
```

if field followers above is in User schema,

```
 const posts = await Post.aggregate([
 {
   $lookup: {
     from: "users",
     localField: "user",  <- field relation in Post
     foreignField: "_id", <- field objectId in users maybe "_id" 
     as: "user",
   },
   },{$match: {'user.followers.user' : req.user.id }}
 ])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Arif, here followers.user is an array in User schema and not in Post schema. Post Schema has "user" as an object to store mongoose objectId.

Comment: i dont know what you try to do, but if post has "user", just connect localField to "user" & foreign key to "_id" in users, I've updated my answer above.

Comment: { $unset: [ "followers.password", "followers.followers", "followers.following" ] }, 
       { $unwind : "$followers" }
      ,{$match: {'followers.username' : userFind.username }} }  this worked for me :)